# QT5 and QSqlResult.h

Tags: qt5, qsqltablemodel, qsqlquery

I am trying to port my code from Qt 4.8 to Qt5. I find that enum VirtualHookOperation is not populated in line 128 QSqlResult.h. In Qt5 the enum is empty. I dont find this change mentioned anywhere in the changes-5.0.0 document. I am trying to build QSqliteSeeDriver.cpp as part of my project.

Please do let me know of any workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments from the qt5 commit on git:
"
QSqlResult: replace virtual hooks with virtual functions

Instead of virtual functions which would have broken binary
compatibility, virtual_hook() was used to implement the virtual
functionality. Now, since the step to Qt 5.0 allows breaking
binary compatibility, we take the opporunity to simplify the code
using real virtual functions.

SetNumericalPrecision --> setNumericalPrecisionPolicy()

NextResult --> nextResult()

DetachFromResultSet --> detachFromResultSet()

BatchOperation --> execBatch() "